# Multiple Vuetify Data Tables causing terrible performance?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm building out a Nuxt app with Vuetify, and am running into a performance issue using the [Vuetify Data Tables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props).

On page load, I am querying for all of a user's trips. The user can then select one of those trips from a sidebar. The example user I'm testing with has a lot of categories and items contained within the first Trip, and nothing in the second Trip. When I click from the second trip back to the first trip, it takes several seconds to load the items.

From what I can tell, this bottleneck is occurring because I'm rendering a new data table for each Category (which then contains multiple Items). When I looked at the Performance tab of the Vue Devtools, I noticed that even though I am disabling pagination, sorting and filtering for the data tables, all of those events are still being fired. Here's the screenshot:

[image: vue devtools]

As you can see, there are upwards of 64 events being fired, most of them are duplicated twice, and events that I thought I'd disabled are still being fired. Here is a simplified version of the code that I am using:

```vue
<template>
  <v-data-table
    v-if="category.items"
    :ref="`sortableTable${index}`"
    calculate-widths
    class="items-table-container"
    dense
    disable-filtering
    disable-pagination
    disable-sort
    :footer-props="{ disablePagination: true, disableItemsPerPage: true }"
    :headers="headers"
    hide-default-footer
    :items="category.items"
    :mobile-breakpoint="0">
    <template #body="{ items }">
      <draggable
        v-bind="dragOptions"
        class="dragArea"
        group="items"
        handle=".drag"
        :list="items"
        tag="tbody"
        @change="log"
        @end="drag = false"
        @start="drag = true">
          <tr
            v-for="(item, i) in items"
            :key="item.id">
            
            <!-- Drag Handle -->
            <td
              :key="`${item.id}-drag-${i}-${index}`"
              class="px-0 py-1">
                <custom-icon
                  color="#4a4a4a"
                  custom-class="drag"
                  :height="20"
                  name="grip-horizontal-line"
                  :width="20" />
            </td>

            <!-- Type Click To Edit -->
            <td
              :key="`${item.id}-type-${i}-${index}`"
              class="px-0 py-1">
                <click-to-edit
                  :style="{ fontSize: '0.875rem' }"
                  :unique-identifier="`type${item.id}`"
                  :value="item.generic_type"
                  @handle-update-item="updateItem($event, item, 'generic_type')" />
            </td>

            <!-- Other Columns, shortened to simplify -->
            ...
          </tr>
        </draggable>
      </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
```

Currently using Vuetify `v.2.4.0`.

Why are all of these events still firing? And is there a more efficient way of rendering a dozen or so Data Tables without taking such a huge performance hit?

Comment: did you test vue performance on chrome or firefox? I had similar issue performance vise (not from data table though), I was testing in firefox and app slowed down drastically, tried some solution with no luck then accidentally tested the app in chrome and everything was working just fine!

Comment: Well that’s interesting. I’m using Chrome currently though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I *sort of* fixed it.

I ended up using Vuetify's [Lazy Component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lazy/), so that it's not trying to render all DOM elements at once. This has sped it up I would estimate by 75%, so **much** better. Not great, but better. Here's how I implanted it:

```vue
<template>
  <v-row
    v-for="(category, index) in trip.categories"
    :key="category.id">
    <v-lazy
      min-height="100"
      :options="{ threshold: .25}"
      :style="{ width: '100%' }"
      transition="fade-transition"
      :value="false">
      <v-col
        cols="12">
        <v-data-table
          v-if="category.items"
          :ref="`sortableTable${index}`"
          calculate-widths
          class="items-table-container"
          dense
          disable-filtering
          disable-pagination
          disable-sort
          :footer-props="{ disablePagination: true, disableItemsPerPage: true }"
          :headers="headers"
          hide-default-footer
          :items="category.items"
          :mobile-breakpoint="0">
    
          ... custom rows

        </v-data-table>
      </v-vol>
    </v-lazy>
  </v-row>
</template>
```

I'm still unsure of why pagination, sorting, and filtering events are being fired even when I'm disabling those via props. I have a feeling it'd speed it up even more, so if anyone knows the answer to that, I would love to hear it!